# OSS: FAIL COMPILATION

Tags: alsa, oss

No install OSS. HELP

All dependencies are satisfied to install OSS:

http://opensound.com/download.cgi

[image]

Comment: Which Linux kernel version are you using? Which package did you download?

Comment: Canonical him to take interest in this issue "if possible":
http://ossnext.trueinstruments.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5811

Comment: Kernel: 4.4.0-34-generic

Comment: CL estás? [....]

Comment: The buildin-essential problem?

Comment: When he tried to install ALSA me not compiled.

Answer (score 0):

OSS is no longer maintained, and does not work with a current kernel.

You'd have to find somebody who has the ability and the motivation to make the necessary modifications to that code. This is unlikely to happen.

So your only choice is to use ALSA instead.

Comment: When he tried to install ALSA me not compiled

Comment: I already know that. So how do I improve the sound of ALSA?

Comment: What do you mean with "improve the sound"? That forum thread you linked to is factually wrong.

Comment: Nor compile my Realtek driver its original site:
http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2